# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child - Unhandled Runtime Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I've been working on trying to create a navbar using a tutorial article I found on [building a 'Strip' style menu](https://www.mikealche.com/software-development/learn-react-animations-by-creating-a-stripe-inspired-menu). This has been a bit of a learning expereince for me as I'm still learning React, NextJs and TypeScript.

Aftr getting some help on a previous problem I'm stuck with now with two more issues:

1. **Object Error (Primary Issue)**

I am receiving a rendering issue when I hover over the menu items. If I comment out `{isBeingHovered && <SubItemContainer>{children}</SubItemContainer>}` in MenuItem.tsx I am able to hover the main menu items, but the submenu items are obviously not shown. The very basic functionality seems to work when I'm not dealing with the submenu items. However once put the above line a code back in I am given the following error

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, text}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

2. **Hashicon Value Error**

After setting my props for SubMenuItem.tsx in navbarType.ts I am still receiving an error on the 'value' in the `<Hashicon value={title} size={25} />`. Part of me thinks this might be due to the Hashicon seeming a bit out of date however (looks like it was last updated 2 years ago) as I mentioned I am still new at this and the error can still easily be between the keyboard and chair. The error that I am being is

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Props |
> Readonly): Hashicon', gave the following error.
> Type 'PropsWithChildren' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context: any): Hashicon',
> gave the following error.
> Type 'PropsWithChildren' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I really appreciate any help, insight or suggestions on this. I welcome any suggestions if I have broken this down in to too many component parts or not too. I have gone and attached the current code below.

**Navbar.tsx**

```
import MenuItem from "./MenuItem";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import SubMenuItem from "./SubMenuItem";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-screen">
      <motion.div className="flex justify-center p-10">
        <MenuItem text={"Home"} style={{}}>
          <SubMenuItem title="Product" text="A SaaS for e-commerce" />
          <SubMenuItem title="Blog" text="Latest posts" />
          <SubMenuItem title="Contact" text="Get in touch" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem text={"About"} style={{ minWidth: 400 }}>
          <SubMenuItem title="The Team" text="Get to know us better" />
          <SubMenuItem title="The Company" text="Since 1998" />
          <SubMenuItem
            title="Our Mission"
            text="Increase the GDP of the internet"
          />
          <SubMenuItem title="Investors" text="who's backing us" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem text={"Products"} style={{ minWidth: 400 }}>
          <SubMenuItem
            title="Ecommerce"
            text="Unify online and in-person payments"
          />
          <SubMenuItem
            title="Marketplaces"
            text="Pay out globally and facilitate multiparty payments"
          />
          <SubMenuItem
            title="Platforms"
            text="Let customers accept payments within your platform"
          />
          <SubMenuItem
            title="Creator Economy"
            text="Facilitate on-platform payments and pay creators globally"
          />
        </MenuItem>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

**MenuItem.tsx**

```
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useState } from "react";
import Underline from "./Underline";
import SubItemContainer from "./SubItemContainer";
import { IMenuItem } from "../../navbarType";

const MenuItem: FunctionComponent<IMenuItem> = ({ text, children }) => {
  const [isBeingHovered, setIsBeingHovered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <motion.div
      className="relative px-10 cursor-pointer"
      onHoverStart={() => setIsBeingHovered(true)}
      onHoverEnd={() => setIsBeingHovered(false)}
    >
      <span className="relative">
        {text}
        {isBeingHovered && <Underline />}
      </span>
      {isBeingHovered && <SubItemContainer>{children}</SubItemContainer>}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```

**SubItemContainer.tsx**

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";

const SubItemContainer: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="py-5 min-w-max">
      <motion.div
        layoutId="menu"
        className="absolute px-10 py-10 bg-white border shadow-lg border-1 rounded-box -left-2/4"
        style={{ minWidth: 400 }}
        initial="hiddens"
        animate="visible"
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubItemContainer;
```

**SubMenuItem.tsx**

```
import { Hashicon } from "@emeraldpay/hashicon-react";
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import { ISubMenuItem } from "../../navbarType";

const SubMenuItem: FunctionComponent<ISubMenuItem> = (title, text) => {
  return (
    <div className="my-2 cursor-pointer group min-w-max">
      <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
        <Hashicon value={title} size={25} />
        <div className="">
          <p className="font-bold text-gray-800 group-hover:text-blue-900 text-md">
            {title}
          </p>
          <span className="text-sm font-bold text-gray-400 group-hover:text-blue-400">
            {text}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubMenuItem;
```

**Underline.tsx**

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Underline = () => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      className="absolute -bottom-1 left-0 right-0 h-1 bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-700 via-pink-500 to-red-500"
      layoutId="underline"
      layout
    ></motion.div>
  );
};

export default Underline;
```

**navbarType.ts**

```
import { CSSProperties } from "react";

export interface IMenuItem {
  text: string;
  style: CSSProperties | undefined;
}

export interface ISubMenuItem {
  title: string;
  text: string;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you've accidentally written `SubMenuItem` to receive `(title, text)` instead of `({ title, text })`

Comment: Thanks Kausko - I can't beleive I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brackets were missing and should have been `({ title, text })` and not `(title, text )` in `SubMenuItem`